# Configure eclipse tomcat to run multiple web application

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, embedded-tomcat-7

I am using Eclipse and configured tomcat in eclipse. I want to run Tomcat in debug mode from Eclipse. I have two application under my server.

```
tomcat-instance
  > site1
  > site2
```

I want these two application to start when I run tomcat in debug/start mode from Eclipse. But problem  is that we can specify only one working directory from eclipse tomcat configuration.

```
 ${workspace_loc:site1/target}
```

So, the other application (site2) is not deployed. So, if I want to check **site2** I have to change configuration. How to run multiple webapplication here.  Does anybody know how to do this ?

Another example is shown below
[image]

Comment: *But problem is that we can specify only one working directory from eclipse tomcat configuration.* - Where exactly?

Comment: I have added an image to the question. Please check it. You will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Define Tomcat server configuration on 'Servers' view, then you can add multiple modules/applications to that instance.